# validates_associated seems not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to ask you a question about the helper validates_associated, since I need to validate a asocciacion. When I try save a new book without associate this a one library the validation does not work

This is my schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140806165743) do

```
  create_table "books", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "library_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "libraries", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end     
end
```

and these are my two models

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :books 
 validates_associated :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :library
end
```

Rails Console

```
library=Library.new(name: "Rayuela")
 => #<Library id: nil, name: "Rayuela", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p481 :003 > library.save
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (3.6ms)  INSERT INTO "libraries" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 06 Aug 2014 21:50:56 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Rayuela"], ["updated_at", Wed, 06 Aug 2014 21:50:56 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true 
2.0.0-p481 :004 > book1=Book.new(title:"Ali Baba",price:50)
 => #<Book id: nil, title: "Ali Baba", price: 50, library_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p481 :005 > book1.save
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("created_at", "price", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 06 Aug 2014 21:51:46 UTC +00:00], ["price", 50], ["title", "Ali Baba"], ["updated_at", Wed, 06 Aug 2014 21:51:46 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true
```

The book1 was saved in the database without to be associated to a library
It has got library_id=nil??????????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validates_associated` simply runs the `validations` that are specified within the `associated object's class`, it does nothing in regard to `foreign keys`.

So,`validates_associated :books` in your `Library` Model simply runs the `validations` which are specified in your `Book` Model(**if there are any**).You haven't specified the `validation` in your `Book` model,so `validates_associated :books` just fails.

You need to use `validates :library_id, :presence=>true` in your `Book` model for your purpose.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :library 
 validates :library_id, :presence=>true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use   `validates_presence_of` for associated data. It Validates that the specified attributes are not blank (as defined by Object#blank?). Happens by default on save.

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :books 
 validates_presence_of :library_id
end
```

`library_id` must be in the object and it cannot be blank. **[More Details](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of)**

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this in your book model,not library:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library
  validates_presence_of :library
end
```